# How to add project specific values to project in maven

Tags: java, maven

1) Is it okay to add this not Maven related custom values in properties tags?

2) Will be there any problems with overriding or something in multi-module projects?

3) Is it a best available solution without adding some extra software layer (e.g. a separate list of projects somewhere)?

I have more than 100 Maven projects and there is developing process all the time.
The new project appears and old projects get outdated.

(upd) We have utility program, that builds a list of jars suitable for deployment. For now, JARs that must not be included in the list are hardcoded in this utility program.

I'd like to add to a pom.xml additional information for our util program that makes projects list for deploying.
For example:

```
<properties>
    <deploy>true</deploy>
</properties>
```

I can't just exclude projects from maven, because I need IDE capability to show usages of methods, classes, etc.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No 3) Depends on how you qualify "best"

Comment: Use versioning..

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen by the best I mean mostly suited scenario for maven. So I will not have to change this in the coming years

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "deploying"? Deploy to Nexus or to a production environment? 2. Do your projects have (Maven) dependencies on each other or are the "independent"? 3. Wouldn't it be good to have a "base project" that depends on all jars you need?

Comment: @JFMeier 1. to a production environment; 2. they have dependencies on each other; 3. there is such project, but the real list of jars for deploy is varies (it depends on degree of completion of development new features). I may have create another one for my purpose, but I'd rather prefer ad-hoc solution, where project can tell every utility programs what to do with it.